# Inconsistent behaviour of getFeature() and getFeatures() when accessing CSV table with no geometry using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, table

I load the following CSV data into QGIS 3 (specs below) as a table with no geometry using default options.

```
"V1","time","V2"
-49,"2021-12-28T00:12:17.725753Z",13.5
-50,"2021-12-28T00:11:17.839767Z",14.5
-49,"2021-12-28T00:10:17.958035Z",14.2
-52,"2021-12-28T00:09:18.078015Z",14.2
```

I open a python terminal to access the layer with `table = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("table")[0]`

When I call `getFeatures()` I see that there are, correctly, 4 features

```
>>> list(table.getFeatures())
[<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x00000215D6518948>, <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x00000215D65189D8>, 
<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x00000215D6518A68>, <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x00000215D6518AF8>]
>>>
```

But when I call `getFeature()` I can access indices 0 through 5, suggesting that there are 6 features. The attributes of the first two features are unusual.

```
>>> table.getFeature(0).attributes()
[NULL, 'time', NULL]
>>> table.getFeature(1).attributes()
[NULL, 'time', NULL]
>>> table.getFeature(2).attributes()
[-49, '2021-12-28T00:12:17.725753Z', 13.5]
>>> table.getFeature(5).attributes()
[-52, '2021-12-28T00:09:18.078015Z', 14.2]
```

My assumption was that these two functions accessed the same data.  But this suggests they don't and now I'm confused.  What's going on, and how do I program defensively around it?

```
QGIS version
3.8.3-Zanzibar
QGIS code revision
685d8b15d2
Compiled against Qt
5.11.2
Running against Qt
5.11.2
Compiled against GDAL/OGR
2.4.1
Running against GDAL/OGR
2.4.1
Compiled against GEOS
3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.0
Running against GEOS
3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 
PostgreSQL Client Version
10.8
SpatiaLite Version
4.3.0
QWT Version
6.1.3
QScintilla2 Version
2.10.8
Compiled against PROJ
5.2.0
Running against PROJ
Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
OS Version
Windows 10 (10.0)
```

Comment: When you loaded the CSV file (using the GUI presumably?) did you handle the header line? What did the preview table show? What does `type(table.getFeature(0))` say?

Comment: @bugmenot123 - the header line was handled (i.e. "first line contains headers") so the attribute table looks as it should. Calling `type(table.getFeature(0))` returns `<class 'qgis._core.QgsFeature'>`

Comment: It needs to be reviewed the source code. There may be a bug. Calling `type(table.getFeature(10000))`  returns a `QgsFeature`, too.

Answer (score 6):

You assume that there is a feature for ids 0 and 1, but  `table.getFeature(0 or 1).attributes()` tells us that it is not true.

The following code prints existing feature ids.

```
ids = [f.id() for f in table.getFeatures()] # list comprehension
print(ids)
# OUT: [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then, continue using `ids` to be sure you use an existing ids.

```
for i in ids:
    attributes = table.getFeature(i).attributes()
    print(attributes)
```

If the table has millions of rows, use of the list comprehension may not be reasonable. Instead, use generator comprehension. Generator comprehensions use circular brackets  `()` whereas list comprehensions use square brackets `[]`. Generators don’t allocate memory for the whole list and  are memory efficient.

```
ids = (f.id() for f in table.getFeatures()) # generator comprehension
```

**Update**:

- if `n` header/skipped line, then ids start from `header + skipped + 1`. That is weird.

For example:

- if no header and no skipped line, then ids start from 1
- if 1 header and no skipped line, then ids start from 2
- if 1 header and 2 skipped line, then ids start from 4